# adding a tooltip/link to angular formly field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-formly

I'm currently using angular formly to generate my forms...its been working great but now im running into an issue where i cant put in tool tips for the forms.

I would idealy want the tool tip when the user hovers the input or next to it....

I made a directive that will allow me to add the tooltips to the individual fields.

formly:

```
        {
          className: "row",
          fieldGroup: [
            {
              fieldGroup: [
                {
                  key: 'page',
                  type: 'horizontalInputFees',
                  name: 'Number of Pages',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: '# of pages',
                    type: 'number',
                    max: 100,
                    min: 0,
                    maxlength: 3,
                    onFocus: hideFieldErrors,
                    onBlur: showFieldErrors
                  },
                  validation: addValidation()
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

tooltip directive i want to add next to the fields:

```
              <li>
                <custom-tooltip id="main-search-tt" placement="'right'" icon-class="'icon-question-circle'">
                  <a ui-sref="pages">Pages</a>
                </custom-tooltip>
              </li>
```

I guess my question will be....is there any way that i can add html next to specific formly fields/inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need to make a directive, you could have simply wrapped the label, or bootstrapLabel template:

```
app.config(function (formlyConfigProvider) {
        formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper([{name: 'bootstrapLabel',
            overwriteOk: true,
            template: '<div>' +
                       '<style> .tooltip-inner {max-width: 375px;}</style>' +    
                       '<label for="{{id}}" class="control-label {{to.labelSrOnly ? \'sr-only\' : \'\'}}" ng-if="to.label">' +
                       '{{to.label}}' +
                       '{{to.required ? \'*\' : \'\'}}' +
                       '</label><i style="margin-left: 5px;" ng-if="to.tooltip" class="control-label-help glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" uib-tooltip-html="to.tooltip.content" tooltip-is-open="false" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"></i>' +
                       '<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>'+
                       '</div>'
        }]);
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Test',
       options: [{ value: 'testID', name: 'Test ID' }, { value: 'Test ID', name: 'Test2 ID' }],
       tooltip: {
       content: $sce.trustAsHtml('Test this out <br\> You can write HTML in here <br\> <b>Bold</b> <i>italics</i> <ul><li>part of a list</li></ul> <br\> ')}
}
```

This will show a UI-Bootstrap tooltip next to the label that will open up when you mouseover it.  You are able to write HTML in the tooltip content inside the templateOptions,  and it will format it properly.